# Newbie Django urls, views, and templates - how can this incredibly simple django project possibly be failing?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

When the user lands at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ I would like to display an html page that says "welcome." When the user goes http://127.0.0.1:8000/time/ I would like to display the current time.  I have followed instructions to the t and dotted every i.  My settings are below.  Why do I continue to get a TemplateDoesNotExist error?

```
views.py

from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.shortcuts import render
import datetime

def current_datetime(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    current_datetime_template = get_template('current_datetime.html')
    context_dict = {'current_date': now}
    return render(request, current_datetime_template, context_dict)

def welcome(request):
    welcome_template = get_template('welcome.html')
    context_dict = {'username' : 'Sally Jenkins'}
    return render(request, welcome_template, context_dict)
```

---

```
urls.py

from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from simpletest.views import welcome, current_datetime

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^time/$', current_datetime),
    url(r'^$', welcome),
)
```

---

```
settings.py

... # all defaults ommitted here - I changed nothing.
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates').replace('\\','/'),
)
```

In my django project directory I have a directory called `templates` and it contains `base.html`, `current_datetime.html`, and `welcome.html` just as expected.

Please tell me what I have overlooked.

Thanks.

MORE INFO:

I am using virtualenv.  Does the fact that I have two django projects in the `/Users/quanda/dev/django-projects/` make any difference?  I can't imagine it would.  One is called "blossom" and is the main project I am working on.  The other is called "simpletest" and I made it extremely simple so that I could isolate the issue I was having in my blossom project.  I am using the same virtual environment for both projects.  Running `tree -L 2` from django-projects/ gives the following structure:

```
.
├── Procfile
├── blossom
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── fixtures
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── onora
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── sqlite3-database
│   ├── templates
│   ├── test_stuff.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── requirements.txt
├── simpletest
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── templates
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
└── virtual_environment
    ├── bin
    ├── django-registration-0.8-alpha-1.tar
    ├── include
    └── lib
```

Comment: P.S. I've read the docs -- in fact, I'm trying to follow them in getting this example to work.

Comment: I have confirmed that TEMPLATE_DIRS is pointing to the correct directory by printing out the value via the django shell

Comment: Can you dpaste your templates, too, please?

Comment: http://dpaste.com/688727/ - base.html  http://dpaste.com/688728/ - current_datetime.html   http://dpaste.com/688729/ - welcome.html

Comment: http://dpaste.com/688725/ - settings.py

Comment: Just to clarify: in the traceback the template should be at /Users/quanda/dev/django-projects/simpletest2/templates,
in your settings.py the path is /Users/quanda/dev/django-projects/simpletest/templates, can this relate to the error??

Comment: You have a sharp eye, but that is not the problem, unfortunately.  I have now deleted the simpletest2 django project and everything is in simple test.  Here is the traceback for simpletest, which is failing in the same way. http://dpaste.com/688732/

Comment: what does your INSTALLED_APPS look like?

Comment: @dannroa - my settings.py is at http://dpaste.com/688725/  INSTALLED_APPS is the normal defaults.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing a template object instead of the template name, as shown here in the traceback:

```
/Users/quanda/dev/django-projects/simpletest/templates/<django.template.base.Template object at 0x102963910> (File does not exist)
...
File "/Users/quanda/dev/django-projects/simpletest/../simpletest/views.py" in current_datetime
  9.     return render(request, current_datetime_template, context_dict)
```

Don't pass the variable `current_datetime_template` - just pass `'current_datetime.html'` as a string, like so:

```
def current_datetime(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    context_dict = {'current_date': now}
    return render(request, 'current_datetime.html', context_dict)
```

Comment: If every simple django bug takes me only 2 hours to figure out then I should be done with this project by 2018!

Comment: Thanks to all who contributed.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in settings.py:

```
CURRENT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__) # for linux
# or
CURRENT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__).replace('\\', '/') # for windows

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(CURRENT_PATH, 'templates'),) # for template dirs
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but I'm getting the same result -- TemplateDoesNotExist.  How can I get it to print out the full absolute path of the template file it thinks it is looking for?

Comment: You could try to install the django debug toolbar to gather some information, you could also provide your traceback here.

Comment: Doublecheck your files and path, you could also try to hardcode the full path in template_dirs and look if that works, I think you are working on windows so dont forget that you need an absolute path with forward dashes like "C:/my/path/to/templates".

Comment: I am on a Mac.  I printed out my TEMPLATE_DIRS at the django shell, and it gives me an absolute path to exactly the directory I expect.  I will nevertheless try to hardcode the full absolute path.

Comment: Im am no Mac specialist, but you should ommit .replace('\\', '/'), because i think Mac uses linux like file path, beat me if i am wrong :P

Comment: I have done that now.  My settings.py is at http://dpaste.com/688725/  I have even tried rebooting my machine!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `foobar` is your django project. Then `welcome.html` should be resides in `/foobar/templates/welcome.html`
and In settings:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = ( os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"templates"), 
)  #for linux and windows
```

Comment: http://dpaste.com/688725/  my account name on the machine is quanda, so my templates should be at `/Users/quanda/dev/django-projects/simpletest/templates`

Comment: I have dpasted my templates just above ^