# How can I print the value of TEMPLATE_DIRS from the django interactive shell?

Tags: django, django-settings, django-shell

I would like to print this value for debugging purposes.  How can I do it?

`print TEMPLATE_DIRS` doesn't work
`print settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS` doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you import the settings first?

```
$steve ./manage.py shell

Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jun 16 2011, 16:59:05)

In [1]: from django.conf import settings
In [2]: settings.TEMPLATES[0]['DIRS']
Out [2] ('/Volumes/HDD/usr/local/django/mytestproject/templates',)
```

Comment: Also, since you seem knowledgeable -- any chance you could glance at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885107/newbie-django-urls-views-and-templates-how-can-this-incredibly-simple-django ?

Comment: `TEMPLATE_DIRS` has since been renamed to `TEMPLATES` if you are using a more modern version

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest, and therefore the ans you may be looking for is to add the following to your settings.py

print ("This is the template.dirs", TEMPLATES[0]['DIRS'])...python 3.x for 2.x leave out the parentheses

so the answer is... standard way to access dict element within a list TEMPLATES[0]['DIRS']

Then when you run your server the  values will be printed out, at the very beginning