# Django admin template overrides not working in production environment

Tags: django, django-templates, overriding, admin

Like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11793890/custom-django-admin-templates-not-working), my admin overrides aren't working in my production environment but they are in my development environment (same django version). I've tried reordering the INSTALLED_APPS tuple in settings.py with no change (was the answer to the question linked above). Here's how I have my project constructed:

```
/WebDJ/ # project dir
    +devices # unrelated app, but it uses templates (see below)
    +sales
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        models.py  # has Customer and Transaction model classes
    +templates
        +admin
            +sales
                +Customer
                    change_form.html
                +Transaction
                    change_form.html
        +devices # lots of templates under here that work fine
        404.html
        500.html
```

also:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = ('/WebDJ/templates',)
```

is set in settings.py. The templates in the devices app are fine. What's not loading are the overrides in the admin directory - so the change form for Customer and Transaction has some extra stuff added to them (overriding the "after_field_sets" block).

Again, it works in my development environment (using PyCharm) but not in my production environment. Any ideas? I'm really stumped on this one.

Comment: Did you restart the production environment ?

Comment: Yep - bounced apache...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Answer: on my production machine, apparently it didn't like "Customer" and "Transaction" despite that being the exact name of the models - it needed "customer" and "transaction".

Comment: I would give you more votes if I could. I wonder why capitalization works in dev but not production.

Comment: if you're developing on Windows and deploying to a Unix variant (such as Linux), then that would explain it - windows directories and filenames are not case sensitive, but Unix ones are. Just a thought.

Comment: Developing on a case-sensitive Mac OS install and deploying on linux so that's not it.

Comment: Same issue here. This even happened between running django on a docker container locally and deployed to kube. I guess that difference could be explained by attached volumes but its certainly surprising.

Comment: Thank you a lot, you've probably saved hours of my life