# django override admin works locally not on production

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin, django-settings

I have the following directory structure in my django 10 project:

```
/my-project/ # project dir
    +app1
    +templates
        +admin
            base.html
        404.html
        500.html
```

My templates attribute looks like this in settings:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            'templates/',
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'common.context_processors.site_info',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

My custom base.html displays on my local machine.  When I upload this to my production server it no longer overrides and uses the base.html file in project folder.

I have changed around the order of apps suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823790/django-admin-template-overrides-not-working-in-production-environment) and tried printing the dirs element of the templates attribute which prints "templates/" like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11793890/custom-django-admin-templates-not-working).

Does anyone know how I can get this to work on my production environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use absolute path in your settings to avoid issues. For example:

```
import os

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', '..')
# depending where your settings.py live

...
    'DIRS': [
        os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates'),
    ],
```